# How to align android buttons like a triangle

Tags: android

How to achieve these two scenarios in android layout -

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: screenshot]

You can add padding to the left and right if you want to separate them from the border.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<Button  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Button1"
    android:id="@+id/Button1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    />
<Button  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Button2"
    android:id="@+id/Button2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    />
<Button  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Button3"
    android:id="@+id/Button3"
    android:layout_below="@id/Button2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />
<Button  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Button4"
    android:id="@+id/Button4"
    android:layout_below="@id/Button3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />
<Button  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Button5"
    android:id="@+id/Button5"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/Button4"
    />
<Button  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Button6"
    android:id="@+id/Button6"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/Button4"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..almost what i wanted except that how should reduce the space between top to buttons.they are very far apart on the edge.

Comment: try with `android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"` and `    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"` for the left and rght buttons, respectively (or any other number that suits your layout).

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"></Button>
        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button2" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button3" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"></Button>
    <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button4" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button5" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button6" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```